# Connecting to CosmosDB using Azure Powershell

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

While am trying to establish connection and query cosmos dB through azure PowerShell, I was facing below error and I added the IP and tried, it was fine but after few days, again similar error occurred. So, Can you please suggest me way to get out of this and let me what am I missing, How can I do this better. Appreciate your help!!
Below is the script am using.

```
    
$CosmosDB_Name = "abtdb"
$Abt_RG_Name = "pre-pprd-cc-abt-rg"
$accountName="pre-pprd-abt-cdb"

$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $accountName -Database $CosmosDB_Name 
 -ResourceGroup $Abt_RG_Name  -verbose 

$query="SELECT c.uuid,c.createdTime,c. actionItemStatus,c. actionType FROM c where c.id='9a73629c-8060-4f23-b25f-fb554d21320b'
order by c.createdTime desc"
$Data= Get-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId 'medias5' -Query $query -QueryEnableCrossPartition $true  -verbose 
$Data
```

[image]

Comment: Where are these cmdlets from? They are not produced by the Cosmos DB team. From the error it would seem to indicate that your client ip is not in the list of allowed ip addresses.

Comment: @MarkBrown : I got these cmdlets from google source via some person. Yes, I have added IP and tried but its not dynamic. IP is getting changed. So, the way which am trying to connect cosmos is correct onr? or is there any otherway. Please suggest

Comment: If the client IP address is changing across subset of IP address ranges then use a CIDR in your IP Firewall rule, such as 10.0.0.0/24.

Comment: @MarkBrown : Yes, but the IP ranges is not like a subset. Its complete different cannot define range.  How we establish connection from local powershell instead of azure runbook

Comment: Then I would not use IP Firewall exclusively to secure your endpoint. You should use service endpoints and communicate to Cosmos over a Vnet.